# What does the phrase "go over or through their own body" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, verbs, phrases, phrasal-verbs

I am not sure about the meaning of the phrase "go over or through their own body" in the following sentence:

> What makes the game challenging is that the birds can neither move
>   backwards nor can they **go over or through their own body**.

The made-up sentence above is based on the text from a puzzle game's description.

Here is reference from a similar game:

> It features hybrid snake-bird animals which are trapped on islands
>   surrounded by water. The player can move the snakebirds around
>   head-first, with some particular elements for movement. The snakebirds
>   can rise by moving upwards, as long as there a body part below, and
>   when falling the snakebird retains the last form.
>
> To complete a level all the fruit scattered around the level must be
>   eaten to unlock the exit. After unlocking the exit, all snakebirds
>   need to be moved head-first into the exit to complete the level. They
>   grow longer with each item of fruit they eat and the player must use
>   this ability strategically to solve the puzzles. There are also many
>   platforms involved. The animals can get stuck and they die if they
>   fall into the water or onto spikes, but the game provides an unlimited
>   amount of undo moves.

Comment: It probably means that the bird-snake can't take a route in the game where it meets its own body and passes through that game square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the classic video game there is a "[snake](https://www.classicgame.co.uk/game/Snake)/bird".  It looks like a long line. If the "head" of the snake touches any part of the "body" of the snake, you lose. So the head of the snake cannot go over the body of the snake.  Nor can it go through the body of the snake. If the head of the snake touches the body then you lose the game.

I don't know why it says "bird" these games usually have snakes or worms. This might be an updated version of the classic game.

Comment: What is the difference between "over" and "through" here? Is the word "through" being used as the synonym of "beneath"?

Comment: It is a 2d game, so there is no "over".  But the player might think that in real life a 3d snake can go over its own body.  But that is not the rule of the game.  It is just telling players that "even though a real snake can go over its own body, in this game it cant go through nor can it go over".

Comment: Can you suggest any alternatives or subsitutes of "go over" or "go through" here?

Comment: Why?  and No.  "go over" seems to be the perfect way of saying "go over".

Comment: Being a non-native speaker I cannot figure out which of the meanings given here is relevant:

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-over

Comment: Can the word "cross" used here in place of "go over"?